# Moving from Chrome to Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Tending to move to Firefox from Chrome due to lack of such things as tools for bookmark management (I merely wished to organize and move some bookmarks by blocks, but noooooo... shoot yourself in the knee game).

Have stumbled on a few things which I hoped to get an answer:

1. I'm usually using a few window approach for a browser (backed by a tab group plugin). And if I have autoplay feature disabled (it's good, but after a few double/triple confirmations for launching a 2 min youtube video my nerves past away) launching Firefox with some windows having yt tabs as last focused will trigger autoplay there (while Chrome only triggers the active window).
2. Again for the youtube. I've noticed that Chrome manages to save the current position of the played video while Firefox fails (and I do believe this is the browser itself and not some extension or option I've touched).

Comment: why are you moving from chrome again? is it because you can't change positions of bookmarks

Comment: I have a bookmark folder, which currently has about 20-30+ bookmarks. I wish to move them to separate folders. I've spent a few hours already(not my first attempt) simply googling and installing every possible bookmarks manager/editor/organizer extension to do this without manually dragging separately all of those bookmarks to the right folders.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firefox allows you to [set Autoplay of media](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/block-autoplay) to globally on or off, or *per* site.
2. Firefox has an add-on, [ResumeLater](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/resumelater/), which is intended to, "Bookmark Youtube videos, saving the current position." That said, I've not used this extension myself.

You also may notice your PC is more responsive using Firefox than Google Chrome, since [Chrome continually scans the PC file system](https://www.vice.com/en/article/wj7x9w/google-chrome-scans-files-on-your-windows-computer-chrome-cleanup-tool).

Comment: 1. Regarding the autoplay. Yes, I found this feature, but didn't get used to it (for me it resulted into more "play" pressing than actually being a help). So had to turn it off.
2. For the "resume later". Youtube, like most other players I've witnessed, have a general "save current position" while the video is being played, which allows me to watch something, then, in the middle, switch to something else, and if I happen to return to that video once more, it will be played from that position. This is native and doesn't call for additional actions like extensions.